# WBXML parser to use for Active Sync implementation

Tags: xml-parsing, activesync, wbxml

Looking for a open source WBXML parser/writer to use with active sync . Do you know a good one ? (JAVA)

Answer (score 5):

I have a good WBXML encoder and decoder implemented in Java (for Android) for my app [(Corporate AddressBook)](http://code.google.com/p/corporateaddressbook/). It works well in regular Java as well.

Look in the wbxml folder (you will need both the [wbxml](http://code.google.com/p/corporateaddressbook/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fnet%2Fvivekiyer%2FGAL%2Fwbxml) and the [activesync](http://code.google.com/p/corporateaddressbook/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fnet%2Fvivekiyer%2FGAL%2Fwbxml%2Factivesync) directories).

Answer (score 2):

[kxml2](http://kxml.sourceforge.net/kxml2/) is the best implementation I've seen so far, you need to provide the codepages for ActiveSync yourself.

Code pages are simple arrays of string (tag names) easily composed from the ActiveSync wbxml specification.